# Transaction ID and Original Transaction ID in google play billing library subscription

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, subscription

I am trying to implement subscription in application using google play billing library.
But in api "GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token" response how can i find transaction id and original transaction id.Is there anything that i am missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the field [orderId](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) for the first purchase the id will look like this GPA.123-123 after it is renewed it will be update to GPA.123-123..0 , GPA.123-123..1 and so on so you can take GPA.123-123 as the original_transaction_id, and orderId as transaction_id